# Mostrar por tiempo un sublayer, Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Quisiera mostrar por cierto tiempo (2 segundos) un sublayer circular que se encuentra en mi función `pointCamera`. Pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo, este es mi código:

```
func pointCamera(centerPoint: CGPoint) {

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: CGFloat(30), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 240/255, green: 240/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 0.3).cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 191/255, blue: 1, alpha: 0.9).cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.0

    cameraView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues lo que creo que tienes que hacer es 2 segundos después de poner el shapelayer, pues quitarlo

después de incluirlo con el cameraView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer) haces un retardo

```
    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        shapeLayer.removeFromSuperLayer()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente con un `dispatch after` te debería funcionar. Así es como necesitarás hacerlo en Swift 3:

```
...

    cameraView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2, execute: {
        shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    })
```